# Is there any way to calculate the weekly data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, logical-operators

I have issue with dataframe. I would like to get the results within starting of the week minus the ending of the week. Is there any way to do it?

| Week Number | Position | Desired Results | Operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 2-2 |
| 2 | 4 |  |  |
| 2 | 6 |  |  |
| 3 | 7 | 3 | 7-4 |
| 3 | 12 |  |  |
| 3 | 14 |  |  |
| 3 | 15 | 3 | 15-12 |

Comment: any reason for 3rd week - 2nd week? I'm assuming the subtraction should be within each week

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Yes, you are correct, should be 6 - 4 for week 2; 15-7 for week 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby` with `transform`:

```
df['Desired'] = df.groupby('Week Number')['Position'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])
```

And now:

```
>>> df
   Week Number  Position  Desired
0            1         2        0
1            1         2        0
2            1         2        0
3            2         4        3
4            2         6        3
5            2         7        3
6            3        12        3
7            3        14        3
8            3        15        3
>>>
```

Or assign to variable first:

```
group = df.groupby('Week Number')['Position']
df['Desired'] = group.transform('last') - group.transform('first')
```

**Edit:**

To not have duplicates, try:

```
df['Desired'] = df.groupby('Week Number')['Position'].transform(lambda x: [''] * (len(x) - 1) + [x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]])
```

And now:

```
>>> df
   Week Number  Position Desired
0            1         2        
1            1         2        
2            1         2       0
3            2         4        
4            2         6        
5            2         7       3
6            3        12        
7            3        14        
8            3        15       3
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Is there anyway to remove the duplicate data in the desired?